# Jump in Sound Design

Tags: sound-design, school, film-school, degree

My name is Riccardo i'm 23yo from Italy.
I'm trying to abandon my work as sound engineer and jump in the world of Sound Design.
Until now i've always passed lot of time working with Ableton Live on synthesis and Audio Recording/Editing, the point is that i think (maybe i'm wrong) i don't have enough experience to start to work in sound design industry, so i'm looking for a good place where to train myself and improve my skills.
I've found few options: Vancouver Film School, Berklee, SAE, and also online courses like Berklee online and Liveshool(Ableton Live).
What should i do in your opinion?
Which school is the best choice? 
Do you think online courses are useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find some short animated videos/or university film student projects to practice sound design techniques on your own. Then simultaneously work really really hard to find someone who has credible skills and some sort of paying work coming in with films so that you can maybe go work for them for free or whatever small scraps they'll pay you to bust your butt and make their job easier. Hopefully you can sort of learn the ropes, impress some people and keep getting asked to come back to work on the next project. Do that until you've "made it"

Answer (score 0):

Enrolling at a college and getting a degree can be very expensive and won't necessarily guarantee you a job. Securing a position as an intern and learning from others may be a better route - on the job training and trial by fire is good for you career and your character.

Answer (score 0):

as you work as sound engineer, why do you really want to go to a school for sound design? You already know many things about sound, so you better seek for an experience in a real company as internship or work in a real project, also for the first time